# Show the identity $\ker A\ne 0 \iff \det A = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't understand the following line from the proof of eigenvalues and charasteristic polynomial:

$$\ker A\ne 0 \iff \det A = 0$$

Thank you

Comment: A non-zero vector in the kernel means a non-zero linear combination of the columns gives $0$. Are you familiar with how column operations change the determinant?

Comment: Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site.

Comment: column / row swaps change the sign by $-1$. So, basically it means that there is some linear dependency, which means that $\det A =0$ due to  alternating form?

Comment: wonder why you've been down-voted. Nevertheless, I presume it's because you haven't shown us what you have attempted. We want to make sure every user here attempts his question before posting it, and this should not be his one-stop shop. That wasn't entirely evident in your question, hence the down-votes.

Comment: It would be more correct technically to claim:  $$\ker A \neq \{0\} \iff \det A = 0 $$ because the kernel of $A$ is a subspace (possibly one that only contains the zero vector, the trivial subspace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $k \in \text{ker}(A), k \neq \vec{0}$. Then because $Ak=0$ , we consider the rows of the matrix A,$A_i$, and note that as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, they are linearly dependent, because we have that $A_1k_1 + ... + A_nk_n=0$ for at least some non-negative integers $k_i$ (these are the entries of $k$). So $A_1 = \frac{-A_2k_2 - ... - A_nk_n}{k_1}$,assuming $k_1 \neq 0$ without loss of generality. In the matrix $A$, we perform the following row-change operation : from the first row, subtract $k_2$ times the second row, followed by $k_3$ times the third row, and so on so forth. Note that we'll eventually get the entire row as a zero row. Note that subtracting multiples of rows doesn't change the determinant,and the determinant of a matrix with a zero row is zero, so $det(A)=0$ . We'll be using this argument later, so note it down if you need.

For the other way ($det A = 0 \implies ker A \neq 0)$, we use the contrapositive way to prove this i.e. we assume that $ker A = 0$ and show that $det A \neq 0$. This will prove it.

Suppose $ker A = 0$. That means, by the rank nullity theorem (You surely must know this theorem) that the rank of $A$ is $n$, where $A$ has dimensions $n*n$. So A has linearly independent rows. Now, we triangularize the matrix in  a manner that does not change it's determinant: figure out for yourself how we make the a matrix of the form

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a\ b\ c \\
d\ e\ f \\
g\ h\ i \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

into a matrix of the form:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
j\ 0\ 0 \\
k\ l\ 0 \\
m\ n\ p \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $a ... i$ are any real numbers, and $j ... p$ are obtained after triangularization. ( Just use row subtraction, and also generalize for $n*n$ matrices.)

I now claim that $j , l $ and $p$, which are the diagonal entries of the matrix, are not zero. Suppose, for example, $p=0$. Then the three rows of the matrix are all vectors in $R^2$, so they are linearly dependent (because they are *three* vectors in a space of dimension *two*,namely $\mathbb{R}^2$),which is a contradiction. If $l=0$, then the the first and second vectors are linearly dependent since they are *two* vectors in $\mathbb{R}$. Of course, if j=0, then the whole first row is zero, so the rows are linearly dependent,again a contradiction.

I'll leave you to generalize this to $n*n$ matrices. For our final step, note that the determinant of a triangular matrix is just the product of the diagonal entries! But none of the diagonal entries are zero, hence their product is non-zero, hence $det(A) \neq 0$!

Finally, we are done. This is a matter of lines if you have the necessary background, but a proof with elementary roots always appeals more to me, and it's better for people who need that kind of approach i.e. work from definition and use standard tricks. Please reply if any doubts.

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much :)